# Add CellPaint event to PictureBox with Grid painted on it

Tags: c#, picturebox, paintevent

I created a Grid on the PictureBox like this:

```
private void PictureBoxPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int numOfCellsWidth = 50;
            int numOfCellsHeight = 600;
            int cellSize = 20;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

            for (int y = 0; y < numOfCellsHeight; ++y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, 0, y * cellSize, numOfCellsHeight * cellSize, y * cellSize);                    
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < numOfCellsWidth; ++x)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, numOfCellsHeight * cellSize);
            }
        }
```

And this is how it looks: 
[image]

I worked with tableLayoutPanel before and it had a CellPaint event which I could bind to a list of arrays so that the color of cells would change when the list is changed. This is what I had:

```
private void tableLayoutPanelMainGrid_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mainVisualization.mainGrid != null)
        if (mainVisualization.mainGrid.cellList != null)
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(mainVisualization.mainGrid.cellList[e.Column, e.Row].color))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
}
```

How can I combine those two?

Comment: You could raise your own CellPaint event in your PictureBoxPaint() method.  Tends to work best when you create your own control class, just make PictureBox the base class and override OnPaint().  Also consider that there will a lot of event handler invocations, maybe you shouldn't dismiss the option to draw in a bitmap instead.

Comment: How could I bind a bitmap to a list? I would have to redraw the bitmap in picturebox every time the list have changed and in my case it would probably be laggy (I'm making a sort of Tetris game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your picturebox is huge I don't think it will be laggy. PBox is double-buffered and should work fine.

Consider this: While your `CellPaint` event **looks** small it really is called for **each** cell **each** time, so the full surface of your TLP is being redrawn **each** time you **invalidated** it. So: Not much different to the situation with PBox..

Here is an example of your own `Paint` and `CellPaint`. It uses a simple 2d-Color array and two `ints` to store the current cell size. **Recalculate** upon **resizing** the `PictureBox` board!

```
Color[,] cellList;
int cellWidth = 23;
int cellHeight = 23;

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (cellList == null) InitCells(22, 22);


    for (int c = 0; c < cellList.GetLength(0); c++)
        for (int r = 0; r < cellList.GetLength(1); r++)
        {
            TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs tep = new 
                TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                    Rectangle.Round(e.Graphics.ClipBounds),
                    new Rectangle(c*cellWidth, r*cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight), 
                    c, r);
            pictureBox1_CellPaint(e, tep);
        }
    // insert the gridline drawing here:
    for (int c = 0; c <= cellList.GetLength(1); c++)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, 0, c * cellHeight, 
                                cellWidth * cellList.GetLength(0), c * cellHeight);
    for (int c = 0; c <= cellList.GetLength(0); c++)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, c * cellWidth, 0, 
                                c * cellWidth, cellHeight * cellList.GetLength(1));
}

private void pictureBox1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    //if (mainVisualization.mainGrid != null)
    //    if (mainVisualization.mainGrid.cellList != null)
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(cellList[e.Column, e.Row]))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
}
```

You can see that it is a direct clone of the code you had for the `TLP`. Not sure if you really **should** do that, but it is an example how you can simulate the `CellPaint` event..

Of course you will want to use your own `cellList` data structure..

It is up to you to decide how you will integrate the drawing of the grid lines.The simplest way is to draw them after the `cellPaint` loop.

By recalculating the cell size (and `Invalidating` the `PictureBox`) it will `resize` its content nicely:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm! This is a very good and detailed answer.